# Which tank to counter enemy picks?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am trying to specialize in tank role and I bought and practiced almost all tanks (miss only Shen).

At the moment, unfortunately, I'm low in ELO and it happens really often that I am the last player to pick.

Supposed that there are no other tanks in my team, what should I look for in enemy team composition and my team composition to select an appropriate tank?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Enemy: Heavy AD** - *Rammus*, *Malphite*, *Amumu*
>
> ~ Rammus' passive naturally scales from armour, giving him higher auto attack damage
>
> ~ Malphite has the ability to slow auto attack speed of enemies
>
> ~ Amumu's ultimate renders those enemies affected unable to **attack** or move for two seconds. Additionally his ability, Tantrum, reduces physical damage received by a flat amount (calculated after the reduction from armor), and the ability's cooldown is reduced by 0.5 seconds for each time Amumu is hit by an attack.

> **Enemy: Heavy AP** - *Galio*, *Mundo*
>
> ~ Galio naturally scales off of Magic Resistance
>
> ~ Mundo has amazing HP regeneration, something that is hard to counter for casters, especially seeing as if they have no anti healing spells (such as katarina), the only feasible counter is the summoner spell ignite.

> **Enemy: Heavy AoE** - *Maokai*
>
> ~ Maokai has an damage reducing AoE
> ult, a great way to counter enemy AoE
> spells

> **Enemy: Tanky Team** - *Cho'Gath*, *Mundo*
>
> ~
> Cho'gath gets seriously beefy if his
> ult has been used well. It can give
> tanks a big surprise due to the only
> tank having true damage.
>
> ~ Mundo with his health regeneration is going to be a very hard guy to take down if the enemy lakes high DPS. His Infected Cleaver ability also deals magic damage equal to a percent of the target's current hitpoints, making him an effective harasser and damage dealer against many tanks.

> **Enemy: Low mobility** - *Singed*
>
> ~
> Singed has extremely impressive mobility and can be an amazing initiator / disruptor with his move speed, AoE slow and fling.

> **Enemy: High mobility** - *Shen*
>
> ~ Shen has a global ultimate that
> can directly counter enemy global ultimates, such as TF's and Pantheon's, shielding the target they are attacking and teleporting to their side to assist them.

> **Enemy: High CC** - *Alistar*, *Mundo*
>
> ~ Alistar's ult removes all CC when cast and can be cast through stuns, silences, and the like.
>
> ~ Mundo's Burning Agony ability reduces the duration of stuns and slows on Mundo by up to 35% at level 5.

> **Friendly: Heavy AoE** - *Amumu*, *Galio*, *Nunu*
>
> ~ Amumu has an AoE root, which sets up
> AoE ultimates on your team perfectly
>
> ~ Galio has an AoE taunt that damages. Nearly as good as Amumu's root, perfect for setting up AoE ultimates
>
> ~ Nunu has a -devestating- ultimate if used correctly. In combination with some AoE CC, his ultimate slows and burst huge damage if allowed to channel to the maximum.

> **Friendly: Lack CC** - *Alistair*, *Cho'Gath*, *Amumu*
>
> ~ Alistair is a CC machine, his
> stuns/knock backs are not effected by
> any CC reduction
>
> ~ Cho has heavy CC, with his AoE knock up and silence.
>
> ~ Amumu has a stun with a relatively low cooldown (however it is a skillshot) and an AoE root, with a pretty large radius

> **Friendly: No jungler** -  *Nunu*, *Amumu*
>
> ~ If you need to jungle as a tank,
> Nunu is probably the best roamer and
> jungler combined,  Amumu is the second
> most capable jungling tank.

> **Best initiators** -  *Amumu*, *Malphite*, *Rammus*, *Shen*, *Singed*, *Galio*
>
> ~ Amumu - Bandage toss into the enemy, and initiate fight with ultimate
> ~ Malphite - AoE stun, with a good range, and an auto attack speed debuff
> ~ Rammus - Roll into enemy carry, stun, taunt them into your team
> ~ Shen - Shield, AoE taunt.
> ~ Singed - Flip a squishy into your team and AoE slow the enemy
> ~ Galio - Flash and ultimate into the enemy

*Oh course the tanks I have mentioned can fill the role of tank vs any type of team, only they are specialised in the areas I have mentioned.*

Comment: Doesn't Amumu also fit well into the _Friendly: Lack CC_ Category?

Comment: I think the problem with Amumu's CC is that it's only on his ult which is pretty high cooldown.  His bandage toss stun is far less reliable since others can shield it relatively easily behind minions.  I didn't write this post so don't take my reasoning as absolute (only played 2 games as Amumu) but that would be my impression of why he might not be included there.

Comment: Amumu's CC can be game-changing. @Danixd - a couple times you mention interrupting an enemy's AoE ult... Aside from Katarina, Miss Fortune, and Nunu, most AoE ults are instant. Pantheon, Galieo, Vladimir, Sona, Malphite, et al all have instant cast abilities, so I don't think recommending tanks based on their ability to interrupt is a useful metric.

Comment: I added Amumuto the Friendly: Lack CC Category and removed Cho and Shen from the EnemyL Heavy AoE Category, as I totally agree with you both. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not ranked myself, but maybe I can help you a bit.

1. Is the enemy specialised in Magic damage or Physical damage?
2. Will you need stun, taunt over other skills?
3. Can your ally take many damage (I think of Singed for example)
4. What can your allies do (in term of stun etc...)

By the way a tank should lead attacks in most cases (that is what I understood from my games), unless you have some second igniter like Eve or Shaco who can do it while invisible. So you need a tank that has such a capability.

Comment: I think that's mostly valid, although you should definitely include "do we have someone who can initiate?" to the list of questions.  It might be more suited for summoner skill choice (use of flash?) but it is certainly a factor in the decision, as some champions are much better suited to initiation than others.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy Magical Damage Team is best countered by Galio, why? his passive 50% of his MR is converted into AP.

Heavy DPS Team is best countered by Malphite, why? his ability *Ground Slam* has a attack speed debuf, build in top of that a *Frozen Heart*

Heavy mobility team is best countered by Shen, why? His global ultimate.